# CSS reorder two inline items

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I have the following code

```
<span>Foo</span><span>blah</span>
```

How can I swap the position of Foo and blah. I tried to put Foo with a float right but it sends it to the far right of my line while I just want it to be on the right of blah.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span>Foo</span><span style="float:left">blah</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating will cause the `<span>` elements to become block-level elements. If that is not your intention, you can use the `inline-flex` property ([see browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)):

```css
p {
  display: inline-flex;
}
p span:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Foo</span><span>blah</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span:last-child {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span>Foo</span><span>blah</span>
```

Of course, this only works in this narrow use case, where these elements are the only elements at the start of the line.

Comment: *For OP:* In the snippet `:last-child` is `script` but will work for your code. `:nth-child(2)` will work for the snippet here.

Comment: The selector is irrelevant. The left float is key.